# Slideout Bug Triggering Twice

Tags: jquery, events, event-bubbling

Having some issues with events triggering in a weird way. If you hit open and close a few times on the jsfiddle below you will see what's happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzs7x4ab/5/

```
$('.btn-open-wrapper').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".blackboard-wrapper").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function (event) {
        $('.btn-open-wrapper').addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.btn-close-wrapper').addClass('is-visible');
    });
    $('.blackboard-wrapper').addClass('is-open');
});


$('.btn-close-wrapper').on('click', function (event) {
    $('.btn-open-wrapper').removeClass('is-hidden');
    $('.btn-close-wrapper').removeClass('is-visible');

    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".btn-close-wrapper").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function (event) {
        $('.blackboard-wrapper').removeClass('is-open');
    });
});
```

Comment: ...and what's happening? And what's the expected result?

Comment: When you open it for the second time, you'll notice that the black square doesn't remain open like it did the first time. I would like the second time you hit open to function exactly like the first.

Comment: Got it, had to try in different browsers... I can notice that the issue only happens in **Chrome** while FF does it well (the reason of my comment above)

Comment: Roko, ah weird, you're right - didn't do any testing on other browsers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Firefox does it pretty well)
The reason is camelCase `transitionEnd` (you did not used)

***[Fixed (test in Chrome)](http://jsfiddle.net/rzs7x4ab/7/)***

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the expressions when clicking close. [Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lsvss3e/) to compare to your code.

For example:

```
$(".btn-close-wrapper").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function (event) {
  $('.blackboard-wrapper').removeClass('is-open');
});
```

should be:

```
$("#blackboard-wrapper").one("transitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function (event) {
  $('#btn-open-wrapper').removeClass('is-hidden');
  $('#btn-close-wrapper').removeClass('is-visible');
});
```

Edit: Oh wait, it's the camelCase issue. My code has different behavior.